# Python regular expression to print out sections of a string

Tags: python, regex, string

Here is my code (apologies for the lengthiness of `testString`, I was not too sure how to format it):

```
testString = """{"id":"174833828503074873","classid":"217769142","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":1},"174833828503117736":{"id":"174833828503117736","classid":"217769142","instanceid":"574274862","amount":"1","pos":2}asdf234sadf"""
sections = re.findall(r'{.*}', testString)
for section in sections:
    print section
```

I want to extract the following two strings out:
`{"id":"174833828503074873","classid":"217769142","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":1}`
`{"id":"174833828503117736","classid":"217769142","instanceid":"574274862","amount":"1","pos":2}`

However, when I print the sections, it extracts both the first and second items and combines them into one string:

```
{"id":"174833828503074873","classid":"217769142","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":1},"174833828503117736":{"id":"174833828503117736","classid":"217769142","instanceid":"574274862","amount":"1","pos":2}
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need regex for that?

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `?` quantifier after `*` to do a reluctant match(shortest possible match).Basically  `*` only will do a greedy match.

```
sections = re.findall(r'{.*?}', testString)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sB7nQ7/1)

```
>>> import re
>>> testString = """{"id":"174833828503074873","classid":"217769142","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":1},"174833828503117736":{"id":"174833828503117736","classid":"217769142","instanceid":"574274862","amount":"1","pos":2}asdf234sadf"""
>>> sections = re.findall(r'{.*?}', testString)
>>> for section in sections:
...     print section
... 
{"id":"174833828503074873","classid":"217769142","instanceid":"0","amount":"1","pos":1}
{"id":"174833828503117736","classid":"217769142","instanceid":"574274862","amount":"1","pos":2}
```

Comment: Sweet demo, I can see how that website can come in handy in the future :D